# Firebase Realtime DB "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a REST query for an app but I'm suddenly experiencing an error I've never gotten before. When I try to sort responses by their timestamp I get the error:

> error: "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"

My URL looks like https://{db url}.firebaseio.com/users/{user id}/surveys.json?auth={auth token}

My rules are set up like this:

[image: My rules are set up like this]

And database is structured like this:

[image: And database is structured like this]

If I add `?orderBy="timestamp"` the error shows up.

I am using correct quotation marks in query and have data indexed by timestamp in my rules. What could be happening here? Why would this suddenly no longer work after using it for a long time?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a URL that gives that error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure thing, I added a sample URL and some snapshots of rules and DB setup

Comment: I don't immediately see what the problem is. Can you replace the screenshots with the actual textual content, so that I can try to reproduce it. For the database itself, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl then

```
curl 'https://{db url}.firebaseio.com/users/{user id}/surveys.json?auth={auth token}&orderBy="timestamp"'
```

for fetch url :

```
https://{db url}.firebaseio.com/users/{user id}/surveys.json?auth={auth token}&orderBy="timestamp"
```